# How to disable body bouncing back in phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework

I have a player and a coin. The coin moves towards the player at `400 per pixel`, when it collides with the player the player is thrown back. How can I make the player stand still as if nothing had occurred?  I tried setting immovable property to player but no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want `game.physics.arcade.overlap` instead of `collide`. `collide` will try and separate your sprites; `overlap` will just let you know that they touched. If you don't do anything in your overlap callback then the sprites will pass right through each other.

I use `overlap` a lot more than I use `collide`.